# How do you pass certain AWS Cognito sign in event attributes to lambda function?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

So I am writing a post-authentication lambda trigger that will grab some of the attributes and place them in a dynamodb table. Using a separate lambda function, the table will then be called to print out the information on a login history page as soon as a user signs in. I want the table to have columns for cognito sub id, date/time information, ip address of user, and location of user. This information is all available in the user pool so I know aws is logging the information. I can get sub using `${event.request.userAttributes.sub}` and I can also get the dateTime but I cannot find the name of the attribute to get the ip address and the location.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use the username and pool id from the event to make an api call to AdminListUserAuthEvents (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminListUserAuthEvents.html).

You'll need to have Advanced Security set to Enabled or Audit for the api call to work.